# Custom webapps directory in Jetty

Tags: html, directory, jetty

I'm running Jetty through command line `java -Djetty.port=8082 -jar start.jar`. I need Jetty only for serving HTML files that would be viewed locally in web browser.

I wonder how can I specify the path to the directory where the HTML files are located? I mean the files are located in the location other than default Jetty webapps directory. Please note that I cannot manipulate files in Jetty directory.

Regards, Rafal

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Multiple webapps source](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Multiple+WebApp+Source+Directory)